# How to link CSS in asp core MVC

Tags: css

I can't get my CSS files to work. I keep getting error 404. Apologies if this is really straightforward but I just can't get it to work.

I have a project in visual studio with the following folder structure:

```
 -Properties
 -launchSettings.json
-wwwroot
 -css
  -site.css
 -images
 -script
  -site.js
-Pages
 -Shared
   _layout.cshtml
 -index.cshtml
   -index.cshtml.cs
-appsettings.json
-Program.cs
-Startup.cs
```

my startup.cs file

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Configuration = config;
        }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
  }
}
```

my _layout.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Welcome to JellyZone</title>
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/script/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body onload="fadeIn()">
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

my index.cshtml is:

```
@page
@{ Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Login.cshtml";}
```

And whenever I try to debug this it gives me error 404.
I've looked online lots and tried using "@Use.Content("~/css/site.cs")" on the link and href and moving the folders into different locations etc.

Please help

Many thanks

Comment: Does `~/script/site.js` provides same error?

Comment: it wont link to any of the files. css, js or image. they all come up with the same issue

Comment: Have you tried without `~`? Just `href="/css/site.css"` or `href="css/site.css"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried physical path too. nothing seems to link them

Comment: I am not ASP developer, but maybe when building you forgot to include these files in build? Maybe your webroot is not actually `wwwroot` and you need to state it `href="/wwwroot/css/site.css"`?

Comment: When i created the program, the wwwroot folder was missing. I added a copy from another project. I've also tried moving the files to other locations and specifying that location.